# How trigger Jenkins to build a project?

Tags: github, build, jenkins, triggers, webhooks

I have the task to run a *build task* whenever the source code in *github* is updated. However I am very new with Jenkins and I have a hard time to accomplish this.

## My understanding

*github.com* will send a `POST` message to a specific URL that I specify. As an example let's use:

```
http://mywebsite/src-updated
```

So the source code get's update, github sends the `POST` message to `mywebsite/src-updated`. Since HTTP runs on port 80, Apache receives this message.

```
 ____________LAN____________ 
|                           | 
| ..........   ..........   |  
| :JENKINS :   :APACHE  :   |     POST message to:                ..............
| :Listen  :   :Listen  :<--|<----http://mywebsite/src-updated--- : github.com :
| :on 8080 :   :on 80   :   |                                     :............:
| :........:   :........:   |     
|___________________________|
```

## My frustration

Now what?

Jenkins sits there like a loser with no-one wanting to play with him. How will Mr. Jenkins get the message? Is there some module I have to install on Apache so that it notifies him? All this sounds very different from the sparse information I read so far so I feel that I am totally off track.

I also tried to use the Github plugin but I am totally lost on how it's supposed to work (terrible documentation if you're new to the whole thing).

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Please check this [link](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Running+Jenkins+behind+Apache) on configuring Jenkins with Apache. Besides, i also found this note on the [GitHub plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/GitHub+Plugin) page:

Jenkins inside a firewall:
*In case your Jenkins run inside the firewall and not directly reachable from the internet, this plugin lets you specify an arbitrary endpoint URL as an override in the automatic mode. The plugin will assume that you've set up reverse proxy or some other means so that the POST from GitHub will be routed to the Jenkins*.

As far as running builds is concerned whenever source code in GitHub is updated, it's very simple to configure in Jenkins. There is a polling option present in the job's/project's configuration page. Go to the configuration section of the job. Search for `Build Triggers` section. You will find a check-box named `Poll SCM`. Enabling this option tells Jenkins to initiate a build as soon as it finds a change in the repository (in this case, GitHub) you specified. You will have to specify some interval after which it will check GitHub for changes:

For example,

```
# every fifteen minutes (perhaps at :07, :22, :37, :52)
H/15 * * * *
```

For more options and details on the above, don't forget to look for the help section '**?**'
[image]

Comment: OTOH one does not need to poll for changes if one has configured the Github project to notify Jenkins webhook. Then just install the Github plugin in Jenkins and in the job config check the box that says "Build when change is pushed to Github".

Comment: That's right @sti and it's definitely a better (and efficient) way than what i described above.